# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar un número que hay en una posición introducida por el usuario en un array en java?

Tags: java, array

me gustaría saber como puedo conseguir el número que hay en una determinada posición introducida por el usuario. Es decir, si yo le pido al usuario que me introduzca una posición y él me introduce la 5, que me muestre que número del array, está guardado en esa posición.

Por ejemplo: este sería el código que tengo:

```
private static int[] array;
    
    private static Scanner sc;
    
    private static int pideTamanyo() {
        
        System.out.println("¿Qué tamaño debe de tener el array?: ");
        return sc.nextInt();
        
    }
    private static void inicializar (int tamanyo) {
        
        sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        array = new int  [tamanyo];
    }
    
    private static void pideNumeros() {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            
            System.out.print("Introduce el número " + (i+1) + ":");
            array[i] = sc.nextInt();
            
        }
        
    }
        
    private static int pidePosicion() {
        
        System.out.print("¿Qué numero quieres ver?: ");
        return sc.nextInt();
    }


    private static void dispose() {
        
        if (sc != null) sc.close();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int tamanyo = pideTamanyo();
        inicializar(tamanyo);
        pideNumeros();
        int posicion = pidePosicion();
        dispose();
            
    }

}
```

Comment: Lee la posición del array que le estás pidiendo. Es el índice, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando pida número el usuario, solo tienes que introducir la posición como índice del array.

```java
int[] aa = {1, 2, 3, 4} // Array defecto introducido por el user

// el usuario pone posición 3
int pos = 3

System.out.print(aa[pos]);
```